# Change filename in Preview

Tags: finder, preview, macos

I end up with lots of screen shots that look like this:

[image: screenshot]

Obviously after a while I do not know what they are.

So I open them in Preview to see, and would like now to change the file name to something meaningful.

How do I change screenshot name **while viewing** in Preview.

Or is there a way to name the screen shot at the time it was taken (without auto assigning the file name). Basically, take the screenshot- pause + popup asking to name the file before it is saved, while it is still fresh in my memory what it was.

Right now I have to exit Preview while trying to remember the

> "§$%&/()?*☂☠

and rename it in Finder.

I can skip the Preview and use Finders Icon or Clover view but that is not the point of my question.

Edit: My Preview must be broken since I do not have the Pull down popup

[image: pull down]

Preview Version 7.0 (826.4)

MBA 10.9.5

Comment: You could also use Cover Flow view in Finder. Then you can see exactly which file you are renaming.

Comment: @Mark, I believe to have specified that in my Question already (see last sentence)

Comment: It's easier than icon view as you shouldn't have to change the icon's size. It's also why I left a comment and not and answer, it doesn't fit your criteria, but I thought it might be helpful.

Comment: I just noticed on 10.10.3 that the arrow doesn't appear until you hover the cursor over the filename in the title bar.

Comment: I am hovering.... and nothing, it might be the Mavericks or my Preview.

Comment: That's too bad. The only other thing I can think of is right clicking or command clicking on the filename.

Comment: question eligible for bounty in 2 days  so lets see..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of June 11 2015 I have not found a solution how to rename a file while in Preview on Mavericks. (10.9.5)

There is also no Save-as function so any changes are saved over the original file.

The `defaults write com.apple.Preview ApplePersistence -bool no` does nothing.

My work around is to use the "Export" where I can rename and save the file.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Yosemite (10.10) but I believe this feature has existed for a long while...

Simply open the file in preview and click on its name at the top of the preview window.

See screenshot:

[image: Preview rename interface]

Comment: Excellent screen shot, but you forgot the "웃"

Comment: Well my Preview must be broken. I do not have pull down arrow.

Comment: Might be a 10.10 only feature

Comment: I had it and used it all the time! But when I reinstalled, [it has disappeared](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/234907/143729). Any idea how to turn it back on?

Comment: I also lost this pull down menu.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in macOS High Sierra 10.13

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening the file in Preview, you could

- select the file in Finder
- press <kbd>Space</kbd> to show the picture
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (even with the screenshot still showing) and rename the file

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Preview you could select the files in Finder and use the `Quick Look` icon to check the contents. I only actually use Preview for multi-page files or those with lots of detail. (I actually use similar in my File Manager `QuollEyeTree` which is much easier to rename.)

Comment: Thank you, the problem is I got used to use Preview :( was hoping someone can cam up with a script that would ask to enter file name during the screenshot process.